# length of valid string returns 0

Tags: java, string, string-length

I have a String

```
String A;
```

and some methods handling it

```
public void setA(String A) throws AInvalidException{
    if(isAValid())
        this.A = A;
    throw new AInvalidException();
}

public boolean isAValid(){
    int aLength = getA().length();
    return b = (aLength==9) ? true: false;
}

public String getA(){
    return A;
}
```

When I try to see the length of my string in main

```
AClass.setA("123456789");
```

it says that my String is invalid and after debugging I saw that the length of my String is zero. What possibly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are code is trying to validate the old A, not the new one.

Comment: `return b = (aLength == 9) ? true : false;` This is some horrible code

Comment: `return b = (aLength == 9) ? true : false;` can be simplified to `return b = aLength == 9;`

Comment: @SJuan76 why is it horrible...? it is a simplified if - else statement

Comment: @VassilisDe: Not that part, the fact that you combine an assignment (`b = `) with a return statement `return ...`. Furthermore you alter some variable `b` why your method only has the responsibility to *check* something. Most people agree that validators never should alter state.

Comment: The issue is that the line is doing two things, assigning to `b` and returning a value. Nobody expects an assignment in the middle of an expression. If `b` assignment is needed, then part it in two lines: `b = (aLength == 9? true : false); return b;`

Comment: Also, `aLength == 9? true : false` is redundant. It is identical to `aLength == 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the String is invalid.

When you create a new instance of `Foo`, `A` is `null`. When you call `setA`, `setA` calls `isAValid` but that method uses the current value of `A`: thus `null`.

You need to parameterize `isValid`:

```
public class Foo {

    private String A;
    private boolean b;//??

    public boolean isAValid (String a) {
        int aLength = a.length();
        return b = (aLength==9) ? true: false;//why do you set b?
        //proposal: change to
        return (alength == 9);//and don't set b
    }

    public void setA(String A) throws AInvalidException{
        if(isAValid(A)) {
            this.A = A;
        } else {//add else, otherwise you will always throw an exception
            throw new AInvalidException();
        }
    }

    //...


}
```

Furthermore you also need to add an `else` statement, otherwise your `setA` method will **always** throw an exception.

Finally it is not crear why you use `return b = ...`, I assume `b` is some field. First of all most programmers agree such syntax is very confusing, next you alter the state of the object by performing a check, you better split methods in altering methods (setters) and checking methods (getters and others)...

It is also very unclear why you use `(condition) ? true : false`. Since condition already returns `true` or `false` you can simply state: `return condition`, or in your case `return b = condition`.

Comment: although I keep boolean variable, cause I have some for loops in my methods and I solve the return problem that way

Comment: I'm quite interested to see the application. Actually I've never seen a case where this was necessary, not to validate input where the constraint is that simple... In most cases, having to use such variable is a sign of bad design decisions.

Comment: I see something else now.. I write `if(isAValid()) this.A = A; throw new AInvalidException();` and you say `if(isAValid(A)) {
            this.A = A;
        } else {//add else, otherwise you will always throw an exception
            throw new AInvalidException();
        }` Aren't they same? If the if statement is false it will go to the following statement

Comment: If the `if` statement is false, it will indeed throw the exception. The problem is that when the condition is true, `A` is set, but then the CPU will execute the next statement as well: throwing an exception. I assume that if your input is valid, you don't want to throw an exception?

Answer (score 5):

While validating you are reading from the place where you set it after validation

change it to

```
if(isAValid(A))
```

and

```
public boolean isAValid(String str){
    if(str == null) return false; //it could be null as well

    int aLength = str.length();
    return b = (aLength==9) ? true: false;
}
```

note: you should follow naming convention

Comment: I commended out the `if(isAValid))` and `throw new AInvalidException();` statements from `setA()` method and it returns 9. So I have to check validation to another point in my code. Thanx!

Comment: probably, one also need to add an `else` case for the exception... Otherwise the method will always throw an exception...

Comment: returning `boolean` would be better than throwing an `Exception` for this kind of private validation

Comment: That's the difference between total/defensive programming. I mean at the level of the `setA` method. It is reasonable to throw some exception when you try to set a variable with an invalid value. But returning a boolean is of course reasonable as well...